# Chrome OS bash script if statement error

Tags: bash, if-statement, operator-keyword, google-chrome-os, crosh

Im running Chrome OS in dev mode, and I am creating a bash file. The code looks like so:

```
echo -n "Username: "
read username: "
if [ $username == "mycroft" ]; then
    echo "Correct!"
fi
```

My problem is that when I run the code in `crosh` with `/bin/sh ./login.sh`, after I type
in `mycroft`, I get this error:

`[: 4: mycroft: unexpected operator`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is the command `read username: "` with the colon (:) and the double quote (") in your actual code, or just a copy paste error?

Comment: Also your quotes are the wrong way. It should be `if [ "$username" == mycroft ];`

Comment: shell `[`/`test` equality is `=` not `==`.

Comment: @EtanReisner `==` is OK in `bash`, though not recommended.

Comment: The code you posted, with or without the extraneous `: "` in the second line, would produce different errors than you one you show.

Comment: @chepner Indeed. The first two comments by user000001 are almost certainly the root of the problem. I just figured to add an additional detail.

Comment: Yes. The : " was a copy paste error.

Comment: you forgot a hashbang

Comment: @user3861375 Then you should edit your question to include your *actual* code, if the issue is still unresolved (prepend each line with four spaces, to format the code).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on the second line

```
echo -n "Username: "
read username
if [ $username = "mycroft" ]; then
  echo "Correct!"
fi
```

Comment: Well, [according to the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869727/chrome-os-bash-script-if-statement-error#comment38630436_24869727) the code in the question is not the actual code he is using, so it is rather difficult to tell when is the real issue in question.